# Drawing Polyline with mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a drawing application with WPF.

I use a Canvas and I draw Polyline on where the MouseMove event triggers.
But some artifacts are created during the process :

**StrokeThickness at 4** :

[image: With StrokeThickness at 4]

**StrokeThickness at 15** :

[image: With StrokeThickness at 15]

The red points represent where the MouseMove triggered, and the gray line is, of course, the Polyline with all the red points.

Any ideas why I get this ?

Comment: Is there any simple code we can run to replicate this?

Comment: Yes, I can provide a sample (I will edit my post in the next 5 minutes)

Comment: I can't create the issue in an empty project...

Comment: As in, the issue is fixed in a new project, or it's tricky to extract the code?

Comment: If you follow the advise in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the Stack Overflow help Center, then you'll either end up with a concise, but complete, working example that reproduces your problem which you can then post here, or you will just find and solve your problem in the process.

Comment: Chris : It's tricky.
Sheridan : I'll read it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `StrokeLineJoin=Miter` then you can use `StrokeMiterLimit` to control how far out the miter extends.

(`StrokeLineJoin=Mitre` is the default on a `PolyLine`)

Alternatively, you can use `StrokeLineJoin=Round` to get a nice transition between segments.

Use `StrokeStartLineCap` and `StrokeEndLineCap` if you want different ends.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="points">0,0 10,30 15,0 18,60 23,30 35,30 40,0 43,60 48,30 100,30</PointCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeMiterLimit="10" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeMiterLimit="5"  Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeMiterLimit="1"  Points="{StaticResource points}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeMiterLimit="10" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeMiterLimit="5"  Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeMiterLimit="1"  Points="{StaticResource points}" />
    </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
            <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
            <Polyline Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" Points="{StaticResource points}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes !! Thank you very much. It worked with `StrokeMiterLimit="1"`and `StrokeLineJoin="Round"`.